# Linux Ubuntu - use .service file to ExecStart with same exact path as with systemctl start

Tags: linux, ubuntu, services

I'm fresh to Linux, so maybe my question will not seem clear. Hope I'll learn enough of Linux in the future, to be more concise.

The problem is, we have service (Thingsboard 3.6.1PE) running on our server, that crashes without apparent reason (white-labeling seems to be the cause, but I don't know this operationg system enough to do more thorough searching). I've decided to restart service automaticaly, whenever it crashes. Not the best solution, but it should do the work.

I've modified `/etc/systemd/system/thingsboard.service` as such:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/share/thingsboard/bin/thingsboard.jar
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s
```

It allows to use `systemctl start thingsboard` - service works fine afterwards. But I would except that after using of `systemctl stop thingsboard`, it should automaticaly restart. It does not - instead it goes inactive:

```
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/thingsboard.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2024-02-01 11:45:10 CET; 4s ago
    Process: 1493891 ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/share/thingsboard/bin/thingsboard.jar (code=killed, signal=TERM)
   Main PID: 1493891 (code=killed, signal=TERM)
        CPU: 7min 53.762s
```

It goes live after `systemctl start` anyway:

```
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/thingsboard.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-02-01 11:46:06 CET; 1s ago
   Main PID: 1496816 (bash)
      Tasks: 28 (limit: 9388)
     Memory: 198.9M
        CPU: 5.612s
     CGroup: /system.slice/thingsboard.service
```

So here's going my question:
What should I put into .service file to make it restart?
Please excuse me if it's a silly question, but I'm still very fresh to Linux and I have to make sure this service works way more robust. I'll be very grateful for any responses. Maybe I should do it the other way (I do not know about yet).

Comment: "after using of systemctl stop thingsboard, it should automaticaly restart" ... That's by design. If it were possible to set up a service to restart automatically after explicitly being stopped by the administrator, it would probably drive most admins crazy. Instead, to test `Restart=Always`, kill the process externally, or make it die by some other means

Comment: Thank you @muru, that exactly what I needed to test it with kill. It seems to work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by [@muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) in this [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/768229/linux-ubuntu-use-service-file-to-execstart-with-same-exact-path-as-with-syste#comment1466271_768229):

> "after using of systemctl stop thingsboard, it should automaticaly restart" ... That's by design. If it were possible to set up a service to restart automatically after explicitly being stopped by the administrator, it would probably drive most admins crazy. Instead, to test `Restart=Always`, kill the process externally, or make it die by some other means